# Converting hex to bin inside the array in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on Visual Studio about Python Project.I have an array and user input for converting hex to dec and dec to bin. I use both of them in my project (hex,dec,bin). Here basic sample of my code:

```
dynamicArrayBin = [ ]
dynamicArrayHex = [ ] 
hexdec = input("Enter the hex number to binary "); 
dynamicArrayHex = [hexdec[idx:idx+2]  for idx in range(len(hexdec)) if idx%2 == 0]
binary = '{:08b}'.format(int(dynamicArrayHex[0] , 16))
```

So, when the user enter `01` for input, the code gives `00000001`. 
I want to separate this result of elements `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1` and put in `dynamicArrayBin=[]`.
After a while when I call `dynamicArrayBin=[0]`,it should show `0`.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You can iterate over a string to retrieve its characters one by one.

Comment: Ah, you want to separate out the bits of all the hex inputs. You don't even need to split out the `hexdec` string into separate digits here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters first of all thank you for helping. However, I only need separate the output of `binary` one by one and put in another array, then I can access all the 8 element of the list. Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: @Asell: is that for a two-character hex input only? What if the input consists of 3 or more hex characters, are you still going to process the input in terms of bytes, 8 bits at a time?

Comment: @MartijnPieters nope I only need to convert `dynamicArrayHex = [2]` and `dynamicArrayHex = [3]` element in the array. No need convert all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a list of binary digits for a hexadecimal input, there is no need to split out the input into bytes first (which is what your code currently does, convert each 2 characters of hex input into an integer covering the range 0-255).

Just convert the whole hex input to an integer, and format it to binary from there:

```
integer_value = int(hexdec, 16)
byte_length = (len(hexdec) + 1) // 2  # to help format the output binary
binary_representation = format(integer_value, '0{}b'.format(byte_length * 8))
```

The `binary_representation` value is a string of `'0'` and `'1'` characters, and since strings are sequences, there is no need to turn that into a list unless you must be able to mutate individual characters.

So:

```
print(binary_representation[0])
```

works and prints `0` or `1`.

If you must have a list, you can do so with `list(binary_representation))`.

Demo:

```
>>> hexdec = 'deadbeef'  # 4 bytes, or 32 bits
>>> integer_value = int(hexdec, 16)
>>> byte_length = (len(hexdec) + 1) // 2  # to help format the output binary
>>> binary_representation = format(integer_value, '0{}b'.format(byte_length * 8))
>>> integer_value
3735928559
>>> byte_length
4
>>> binary_representation
'11011110101011011011111011101111'
>>> binary_representation[4]
'1'
>>> binary_representation[2]
'0'
>>> list(binary_representation)
['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

If all you wanted was the *first bit* of a hexadecimal value, then there is a faster method:

```
if len(hexdec) % 2:  # odd number of hex characters, needs a leading 0
    hexdec = '0'     # doesn't matter what the rest of the hex value is
print('1' if hexdec[0].lower() in '89abcdef' else '0')
```

because the first 4 bits of the binary representation are determined entirely by the first hexadecimal character, and the very first bit is set for hex values `8` through to `F`.

Comment: Guys, Thank for your effort and helping to me. However it didn't what I want, I solved the problem if you copy your answer, other people can get solution.

Comment: Just add after my code: `dynamicArrayBin = [binary[i:i+1]  for i in range(len(binary)) if i%1 == 0]`
`print(int(dynamicArrayBin[0],16))` Result is what I want

Comment: @Asell: sorry, no, I'm not copying your code, because it is doing the same thing, just for the first bit, in an extremely circumspect way. You only took the leftmost 2 hex digits (the value in `dynamicArrayHex[0]`), so you could have used `binary = format(int(hexdec[:2], 16), 8)` and have gotten the same value. `dynamicArrayBin` could be replaced with `list(binary)`, as you just take individual characters. And `print(int(dynamicArrayBin[0],16))` is interpreting either `'0'` or `'1'` as a hexadecimal number, but printing `0` or `1` has no different effect from printing `'0'` or `'1'` however.

Comment: @Asell: so in the end, your current attempt can be replaced with `print(format(int(hexdec[:2], 16), '08b')[0])`. There is otherwise **no difference in output** between your code and my answer.

Comment: Awe @MartjinPieters  I try your solution in clearly, and the result is perfect. you were right. I'm sorry. Thank you so much again. I mark your solution to true one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

```
hexLst = ['ABC123EFFF', 'ABC123EFEF', 'ABC123EEFF']
binLst = [bin(int(n, 16))[2:] for n in hexLst]
print(binLst)
```

Which will give you a output

```
['1010101111000001001000111110111111111111', '1010101111000001001000111110111111101111', '1010101111000001001000111110111011111111']
```

then you can make a list from that

```
dynamicArrayBin=[list(b) for b in binLst]
print(dynamicArrayBin)
```

**Output**

```
[['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1'], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']]
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your effort and helping me but it wasn't my answer. I solved it, can you edit your answer: just write after my code: `dynamicArrayBin = [binary[i:i+1] for i in range(len(binary)) if i%1 == 0]` `print(int(dynamicArrayBin[0],16))`. The result what I want. Then other guys can understand the result.

Comment: Okay @Asell, but there a better to do `dynamicArrayBin = [binary[i:i+1] for i in range(len(binary)) if i%1 == 0]` like simply `dynamicArrayBin = [[i] for i in binary]`